# What is the most efficient way to tile an image using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've been recently working on a platformer, and I'd like to add some images to it.
My goal is to tile an image while using as little CPU/GPU as possible, and I've tried two solutions: drawing each image with `drawImage()` and using the `createPattern` fill style.

#### `for` loop method:

```js
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for (let i=0; i<heightInTiles; i++) { 
  for (let j=0; j<widthInTiles; j++) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, screenX + j * blockSize, screenY + i * blockSize);
  }
}
```

The issue with this solution is that drawing each image separately consumes lots of CPU & GPU. Is there a way to make this more efficient? (Like a 50-percent-drop-in-CPU efficient?)

#### `fillStyle` method

```
var pat = ctx.createPattern(image, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = pat;
ctx.fillRect(screenX, screenY,   
             widthInBlocks * blockSize,
             heightInBlocks * blockSize);
```

This solution doesn't cost as much space, but it has a weird effect: the pattern only aligns itself to the top-left corner of the canvas.

I'm just looking for a faster way to draw the tiles I need onto the screen. Could you guys help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Transforming a pattern

Pattern is by far the quickest way to repeat a pattern using the 2D API. For better results you would need to use WebGL.

To move the pattern you need to manipulate the transform using [pattern.setTransform(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern/setTransform) via a [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix)

### Example

Setting the starting position of a pattern

```
var pat = ctx.createPattern(image, "repeat");
pat.setTransform(new DOMMatrix([1,0,0,1,screenX, screenY])); // set top left starting 
                                                             // pos of pattern
ctx.fillStyle = pat;
ctx.fillRect(screenX, screenY, widthInBlocks * blockSize, heightInBlocks * blockSize);
```

Comment: *nitpick:* DOMMatrix requires `new`. And while I know you do know, just a note that for older browsers that didn't support `CanvasPattern.setTransform`, you could set the one of the context too and counter the translation in the `fillRect` call, or even separate the path declaration and filling on two different matrix transforms.

Comment: @Kaiido There are plenty of legacy examples on SO eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838137/3877726